# ng-bootstrap how get string or Date format no object

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I use ng-bootstrap Datepicker something like here:
[plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wwbmDw23bkKdqc8zvdDG?p=preview)

but now after choose date I get object

```
Model: {
  "year": 2016,
  "month": 10,
  "day": 13
}
```

But I would like get date in this format **2016-10-17**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `NgbDateParserFormatter`

```
import {NgbDateParserFormatter} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

constructor(private parserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter) {}
...
let date = this.parserFormatter.format(this.model);
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t4b4CWCq3P3hoBwkxsmO?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Worked for me. I really don't understand why a (configurable or default) formatter isn't integrated by default into marshalling and unmarshalling between datepicker and text INPUT fields.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the particular properties of the object and construct your date string like this:

```
let date = this.Model.year + '-' + this.Model.month + '-' + this.Model.day
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write typescript like below.

```
date: NgbDateStruct;

ngOnInit(){

   this.date = {
     year: 2016,
     month: 10,
     day: 17
   }

}
```

and print within HTML

```
<span>{{  date  }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below Solution work for angular 5-6-7-8-9:**

> **Import:**

import { NgbDateParserFormatter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

> **constructor:**

private parserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter

> **Get Value:**

this.empForm.value.dobField = this.parserFormatter.format(this.empForm.value.dobField);

> **SetValue:**

this.empForm.get('dobField').setValue(this.parserFormatter.parse(this.empForm.value.dobField));